# JPA specification join many tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I have Shelf Entity, HubProducts Entity, Products Entity.

1. Shelf has HubProducts
2. HubProducts has Product
3. Product has name

```java
public class Shelf extends BaseEntity {
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hub_product_id")
    private Set<HubProducts> hubProducts;
}

public class HubProducts extends BaseEntity {
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "products_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Products product;
}
```

Similarly, Product entity has name field.

Now I want to query using JPA specification such that all records matching with product name should be filtered

For that purpose, I have written:

```java
private static void applyKeywordFilter(CriteriaBuilder cb,
                                       Root<Shelf> root,
                                       Collection<Predicate> predicates,
                                       String keyword) {
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(keyword)) {
        predicates.add(cb.or(
            // Shelf->hubProducts->Products -> [name]
            cb.like(root.join("hubProducts", JoinType.LEFT).join("product",  JoinType.LEFT).get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%"),
            cb.like(root.get("shelfDetails"), "%" + keyword + "%")));
    }
}
```

But Unfortunately   `cb.like(root.join("hubProducts", JoinType.LEFT).join("product",  JoinType.LEFT).get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%"),` does not work.

Can somebody help please?

Comment: Can you specify what "does not work" means? Do you get an error or different results than you'd expect?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, i expect records matching with the product name should be filtered.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to entities Producers, Movie, Actor. Movie had multiple actors and one producers. To perform a search I used this:

```java
private Specification<Movie> searchSpecification(String keyword) {
        return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
            if ((keyword ==null)) {
                return null;
            }
            return criteriaBuilder.or(
                    criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%"),
                    criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("plot"), "%" + keyword + "%"),
                    criteriaBuilder.like(root.join("actors").get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%"),
                    criteriaBuilder.like(root.join("producer").get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%")
            );
        });
    }
```

You refer this to generate you own specification and join tables. Here I have joined 3 tables.